# Como manter uma tecla pressionar no pyautogui

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyautogui

Eu gostaria de manter uma tecla pressionada por x segundos.
Eu sei que dar um toque na tecla é:

```
pyautogui.press("key")
```

Mas como posso mantê-la pressionada?

Answer (score 1):

Como a própria [documentação](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) diz, a função `press` nada mais é que um atalho para a execução da função `keyDown` seguida da função `keyUP`. Ou seja, ao executar a função `keyDown`, a tecla estará pressionada até que a função `keyUp` seja executada. Assim, um exemplo simples de manter pressionado a seta direcionado para a esquerda por 5 segundos seria:

```
x = 5
pyautogui.keyDown("left")
time.sleep(x)
pyautogui.keyUp("left");
```